# Error Installing ImageMagick (with Brew)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, homebrew

I'm trying to install ImageMagick with brew, but keep getting this:

I run the command: `brew install magic

But get this:`

```
Error: undefined local variable or method `x11' for #<X11Dependency::Proxy::Freetype:0x10b827858>
```

**Help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a Homebrew bug which was just [fixed today](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commit/17e83c4f242464c36648b147bb10ed1c89448f55). Is your Homebrew up to date with the latest formulae and supporting files? Try updating it with:

```
brew update
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to update your brew installation

```
cd /usr/local
brew update
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

and then try

```
brew install imagemagick
```